# Mule Salesforce query

Tags: salesforce, mule, datamapper

I am trying to populate a joiner table in Salesforce from data in a database. The joiner table has two lookups (of course to two different objects).

My Flow starts from querying a database. The query fetches has two fields NT_ACCOUNT & CXM_ID - These two exists as separate objects in Salesforce so i have to perform lookup to salesforce to get their corresponding salesforce Id's to create a record in my joiner table. I am not sure of the ideal way to do this

Below is the flow i have which takes NT_ACCOUNT and did a query against SF to get its Id in SFDC and create the joiner record. Now my question what is the ideal way populate the other loop in my joiner which is (a look up on SFDC for CXM_ID in database). Will it be a good option to query for CXM_ID in SFDC for its corresponding SFDC ID and combine both payloads and pass it on create (if yes any pointers on how to do that will help).

```
<batch:job name="Batch2">
        <batch:threading-profile poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
        <batch:input>
            <poll doc:name="Poll">
                <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="1000"/>
                <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT NT_ACCOUNT,CXM_ID from Table where lastmodifieddate = 'within last 24 hours';]]></db:parameterized-query>
                </db:select>
            </poll>


        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step_1">

                    <sfdc:query-single config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_authentication1" query="dsql:#[&quot;SELECT id FROM FM_Account__c WHERE account_number__c = '&quot;+payload.NT_ACCOUNT+&quot;' LIMIT 1&quot;]" doc:name="Salesforce"/>

            <batch:commit size="200" doc:name="Batch Commit">

                    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Map_To_Map_1" doc:name="Map To Map"/>


                    <sfdc:create config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_authentication1" type="Joiner_Table__c" doc:name="Salesforce">
                        <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>

                    </sfdc:create>
                    <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

            </batch:commit>  

            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>

    </batch:job>
```

Comment: I did it through looking up a flowlookup via the data mapper but i am not sure if it is the best way though